# Parsing dates with regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a C# app, and I get a string with a date or part of a date and I need to get the day, month and year for that string. For example:

```
string example='31-12-2010'
string day = Regex.Match(example, "REGULAR EXPRESSION FOR DAY").ToString();
string month = Regex.Match(example, "REGULAR EXPRESSION FOR MONTH").ToString()
string year = Regex.Match(example, "REGULAR EXPRESSION FOR YEAR").ToString()

day = "31"
month = "12"
year = "2010"

ex2: 
string example='12-2010'

string month = Regex.Match(example, "REGULAR EXPRESSION FOR MONTH").ToString()
string year = Regex.Match(example, "REGULAR EXPRESSION FOR YEAR").ToString()

month = "12"
year = "2010"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regular expressions for that.
Instead use

```
DateTime temp = DateTime.Parse(example);
```

Now a lot of useful properties are at your disposal. `temp.Day` e.g.

Comment: that will not work for me because my string can also be "2010" or "2010 12:44". this will make DateTime.parse(str) throw an exception

Comment: Then I'd use DateTime.TryParse and iterate through a few expected formats.

Comment: @DJPB: Ah, you didn't say so in the question. =) 
Update the question to include all possible cases, then.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.ParseExact()` allows you to define the custom format of the string you want to parse and then you have a nice `DateTime` object to use.
But if you say that you can have strange formats like "year hour:minute", I think you can go with a RegEx.

```
    string example = "31-12-2010";

    Match m = Regex.Match(example, @"^(?<day>\d\d?)-(?<month>\d\d?)-(?<year>\d\d\d\d)$");
    string strDay = m.Groups["day"].Value;
    string strMonth = m.Groups["month"].Value;
    string strYear = m.Groups["year"].Value;
```

For the string **"2010 12:44"**, you can use the pattern `@"^(?<year>\d\d\d\d) (?<hour>\d\d?):(?<minute>\d\d?)$"`

For the string **"12-2010"**, you can use the pattern `@"^(?<month>\d\d?)-(?<year>\d\d\d\d)$"`